# Navigate on same page with wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to navigate on the same page with wordpress menus ?

lets say i have only one very long wordpress post and want to navigate on the same page by clicking the wordpress menus ?

Comment: How can i accomplish that

Comment: First read this: [ask] and [faq]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "id" attribute for the element you want to navigate to and bookmark links in the menu. See here [HTML Links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)